# Lower chart in reputation graph is invisible

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-graph

> I first reported it 8 days ago on [Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10825/27741)
>   and later flagged it to be moved to Meta Stack Overflow 3 days later
>   when I noticed it happening to me on Stack Overflow as well.

Is it happening to me alone? I am able to see charts for other users, but it is not shown for myself.

Screenshots to show the bug:

[image: first]

[image: second]

It should be something like (taken as a guest user):

[image: actual]

This behaviour is not displayed only on Meta Stack Overflow but is experienced on all main sites I'm registered on. A few more points before someone else asks:

1. It is only noticed when I am logged in.
2. Changing browsers doesn't make a difference.
3. I do not use any JavaScript blockers or extensions in Chrome (where I normally keep logged in).
4. The bars are somewhat visible when I zoom-out to around 90% as shown in images below:

   - **At 90%**
     [image: at 90%]
   - **At 100%**
     [image: at 100%]

---

I'd happy if I'm not a part of some experiment once again and this is most probably only my own screen and not a Stack Exchange error.

---

**PS:** All images in post are small sized thumbnails and can be clicked upon for larger images.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: @Oded Chrome latest version only, it was already reported two weeks ago and I can reproduce it.

Comment: @Oded I'm noticing it in Chrome Version 29.0.1547.66m but only if I am logged in. Windows 7 x64

Comment: @hjpotter92 downgrade Chrome to fix it... ;)

Comment: @Oded again its not showing in chrome and safari